# Android Receive Email (event)

Tags: java, android, email

I've been looking for a short while but come up with nothing but examples on how to send emails, does Android have a built-in method for when a email is received and the information behind that email (subject, to, body ect.)

All my googling and questions (mainly in IRC) has gotten me no where.

Also, if Android doesn't offer a way to do it, would anyone mind suggesting a good lib? It's a short project and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Appreciate any and all answers, thanks!